# Undesirable borderlines appear when I make `tcolorbox` breakable

Tags: tcolorbox

Undesirable borderlines (although they may seem nonobvious) appear when I make `tcolorbox` breakable (see the red arrows in the following figures). How can I remove them?

[image]

[image]

Here is a MWE. I would appreciate your help with this situation.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,includehead=true,inner=2cm,outer=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[breakable,skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{parbox=false,colback=white}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{myexample}{Example}{breakable,enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,colframe=black!40,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=black!10,borderline={0.4mm}{0mm}{black!40},attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-2mm},boxed title style={boxrule=0.2mm},varwidth boxed title}{}


\begin{document}

\chapter{ff}

\section{ff}

\begin{myexample}{}{}
fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff 

fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff 

fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff 

fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff 

fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff fffff fffff fffffff 
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems this line is a side effect of the `attach boxed title to top` option, since they are not present when you disable this option.

Comment: Replace `frame empty, interior empty` by `frame hidden`. It works for me.